# Which file contains user settings options in RStudio Server?

Tags: r, settings, rstudio-server

Which file contains user settings options in RStudio Server such as appearance theme, code display, etc.: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMLop.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found it:

```
$ grep -irln "theme" ~/.rstudio
/home/rstudio/.rstudio/monitored/user-settings/user-settings
```